# Parsing a text file based on first word C++

Tags: c++, parsing, text, text-files

I'm trying to write a simple program in C++ that **reads information from a text file and prints it to the console**. The text file will look similar to this.

```
thing1 contents1 
thing2 contents2
thing3 contents3
thing4 contents4
```

Is there a way that I can print `contents1` console by knowing that the preceding word is `thing1`?

Comment: Yes, there is a way.

Comment: You want to call a type "function" with the parameter `thing1` and it brings the associated value (if `contents1`)?

Comment: Would you consider using a language like perl instead?  This would be pretty easy in a language designed for file and string manipulation.

Comment: i thought perl was designed for regexs?

Comment: What is your exact goal, do something with contents column data, according to what is specify in thing column?

Comment: dohashi, I've used Perl for things like this before this is just a little project I want to do in C++ NetVipeC, my goal is to in C++ have the user input thing1 or thing2 etc and have the program print the contents1 or contents2 etc that is 'associated' with what the user inputs

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <istream>
#include  <string>
#include  <vector>

std::vector<std::string> getContents(std::istream &stream, std::string mark) {
    std::vector<std::string> contents;
    std::string current;

    while(stream) {
        stream >> current;

        if(current == mark) {
            stream >> current;
            contents.push_back(current);
        }
    }

    return contents
}
```

this is a very basic example. i wouldnt suggest using just this, but it does get the job done. what it does do: if mark is found in stream, grab content. what it does not do: a lot checking to make sure the stream is valid, or that the line is valid (ie the content could come immediatly after mark). This also could probably be done easier on strings, its just my personal preferene to use streams

edit: thought i saw thing1 = content1. looked again and turns out it was thing1 content1. code edited appropriately

Comment: Is there something you would suggest using, Im fairly comfortable with C++ so it san be semi complicated if needed.

Comment: maybe operate on just strings? although istream is still as safe since its the base type for stl streams and most custom stream implementations. if you do use streams, check more than i did. for example, our program assumes that for every thing there is a content. but what if there isnt? our stream doesnt know that and will try to take something from nothing. maybe use something smaller than vector (idk if there is something smaller though)

Comment: For this program for every `thing` there is going to have a `content` as this program writes to a file and then the user has the option to read the data back.

Answer (score 0):

One way, using [*`std::map`*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map)

```
ifstream fin("textfile.txt");

std::string firstw, secondw;

std::map< std::string, std::string> m ;

while ( fin >> firstw >> secondw )
{
   m[firstw] = secondw ;
}

fin.close( );

std::string input_word = "thing1" ; 

// Wrap following in a function, input_word is the search element

if( m.find(input_word) != m.end () )
{
  std::cout << m[input_word] ;
}
```

Comment: why not just std::cout << m[input_word] ; aka why wrap it in an if?

Comment: @DTSCode Because if `input_word` is not present in map, `[]` overloaded operator will add that input the map.

Comment: but won't it just be ""?

Comment: @DTSCode yes but the idea is to retrieve from map not just add new words not found. Here in else part one can handle this.